# Namespace and including script issue

Tags: php

Lets have following php script `MySpace/Scaffold.php` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
namespace Playground\MySpace;  // <-- IT FAILS HERE
…
?>
```

and include it from other script with

```
require_once("MySpace/Scaffold.php");
```

It fails with

> PHP Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very
>   first statement or after any declare call in the script in
>   .../PHP/playground/src/MySpace/Scaffold.php on line 3

I looked through official documentation on php.net but can not find an explanation.

When I remove the first line with `#!` shebang, it starts to include it correctly.

Why PHP does not count statements since first opening `<?php` tag ?
Why it even bothers with above non-php content ?

**Why PHP interpreter (7.2.7, Zend Engine v3.2.0) fails with above error when `namespace Playground\MySpace;` _is_ the first statement in php code ?**

Comment: i doubt you are really running this as a shell script, so no `#!/usr/bin/env php` required

Comment: @smith I *do* run it also as a shell script by checking `php_sapi_name()` result, your doubt is quite out of place. It even does not matter if shebang line is replaced with something else, not clashing with `<?php … ?>` tag. The original question is about a different topic - why PHP throws above fatal error when `namespace` **is** the first statement in the code.

Answer (score 0):

AS you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.usage.php) this sheebang command is meant to be used when the script is excecuted from the command line.

> On Unix systems, the special #! (or "shebang") first line should be added to PHP scripts so that the system can automatically tell which program should run the script.

Because when php is excecuted from a server this is not necesary, this commands are not actually parsed and result in this text being printed in the result file (as any HTML text before the first opening tag would do). (you can check that in your IDE, this line probably appears as plain text)
Because PHP already output something then he complains about setting the namespace.

Comment: This script works like a standalone cli application and also as a set of library classes/functions. If you replace first shebang-line with something else, like `<h1>Hello world</h1>`, the issue persists. Why PHP does not ignore content outside/above `<?php … ?>` when checking `namespace` position ?

Comment: PHP cannot ignore what's outside the <?php … ?> tags because even in cli what is outside the tags is printed (in case of cli, its printed to the console) as seen in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php#example-403). What you must to understand is that the sheebang #! line is **not** for php, is to tell the command line that php (or any program given there) is the one that is going to open the file. Thats why you also see them in other interpreted languages like python (examples [here](http://archive.stsci.edu/vo/python_examples.html))

Comment: I'm well aware what shebang line is and what is used for. I'm also aware content outside of `php` tags is sent to stdout. By *ignoring* I meant in the context of namespace placement rule. I'm only asking why PHP consider `namespace` expression from original example **not the very first statement**, when it actually **is the first one where code block begins**. Is this a bug or a (undocumented) feature of PHP ?

Comment: Being completly honest, I don't know if this is because of a technical limitation or by a PHP estandard, but the short answer would be (sadly) because thats how PHP is. I believe the confusion is that the start of the file for php is **not** the first `php` tag, but the begining of the file as normal. The php parser sees text outside of the tags as orders to ouput them without any modifications, but still output them. So it's like (not the same obviously) if you did an `echo` before the namespace. I think once php starts outputing text, the step of setting the namespace already occurred.

Comment: ..(continuation of my last comment).And no, this is not a bug. As stated in this example: php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php#example-244 no text is allowed before the namespace tags, and as I said in my answer, in the server there is no diference between any text and a `#!` banshee line. That said I believe It's a good feature. I'd recomend you to submit an issue telling that and they will tell you if there is something to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Missed the following claim in namespaces section of PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php):

> In addition, no non-PHP code may precede a namespace declaration, including extra whitespace:
>
> Example #2 Declaring a single namespace

```
<html>
<?php
namespace MyProject; // fatal error - namespace must be the first statement in the 
script
?>
```

In addition, unlike any other PHP construct, the same namespace may be defined in multiple files, allowing splitting up of a namespace's contents across the filesystem.

That's it. Just not supported feature.

Sorry for any inconvenience. Just used to different style of documentation.